# Necessary optimality condition for quadratic programming: a solution of a constrained QAP is a solution of a LP

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization

I have a concern about a result given by Murty in [1]  and also written by Floudas and Visweswaran in [2]

They consider a QP:

\begin{array}{ll}{\min _{x} Q(x)} & {=c^{T} x+\frac{1}{2} x^{T} D x} \\ {\text {s.t.} \quad A x} & {\geq b} \\ {x} & {\geq 0}\end{array}

with no particular assumption on $D$ (appart from symmetric). Murty argues that if $x_{*}$ is a solution of the QP it is also solution of the following LP:

\begin{array}{cl}{\min _{x}} & {\left(c+x_{*}^{T} D\right) x} \\ {\text {s.t.}} & {A x \geq b} \\ {x} & {\geq 0}\end{array}

The proof of Murty is the following:

Let $\hat{x}$ be any feasible solution of the LP and $x_{\lambda}=\lambda \hat{x}+(1-\lambda) x_{*}$ for $\lambda \in ]0,1[$. It is also feasible since the set of feasible solutions is a convex polyhedron.
Then by optimality of $x_{*}, Q\left(x_{\lambda}\right)-Q(x_{*}) \geq 0$ which implies:

$$\lambda\left(c+x_{*}^{T} D\right)(\hat{x}-x_{*})+(1 / 2)\lambda^{2}(\hat{x}-x_{*})^{T} D(\hat{x}-x_{*}) \geq 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               $$

And so dividing by $\lambda$ leads to:

$$\left(c+x_{*}^{T} D\right)(\hat{x}-x_{*}) \geq(-\lambda / 2)(\hat{x}-x_{*})^{T} D(\hat{x}-x_{*})$$

At this part Murty argues that it "obviously implies":

$$\left(c+x_{*}^{T} D\right)(\hat{x}-x_{*}) \geq 0 $$

and hence $\hat{x}$ must be an optimum feasible solution of the LP.

It seems to be false at first sight except when the QP is concave (and D neg definite) so that the rightmost term of the inequality is negative. Am I missing something ?

Ref:

[1] Linear Complementarity, Linear and non Linear Programming, 1988

[2] Quadratic Optimization by Floudas and Visweswaran, 1995

Comment: Murty is correct. Take the limit of the inequality for $(c + x_*^\top D)(\hat{x} - x_*)$
 as $\lambda \to 0+$.

Comment: $Ax \le b$ or $Ax \ge b$?

Comment: But if it is correct then would it imply that any solution of a QP lies in an extremal point of the polyhedron ? This is true for concave QP but in general it seems strong right ?

In [2] it is $\leq$ for the definition of the QP and then $\geq$ for the theorem and in the original [1] it is $\geq$ everywhere. I edit my post

Comment: No it does not imply an optimal solution is an extreme point.  For example, the optimal solution of the QP could be an interior point of the feasible region, in which case the objective of the LP is $0$, and every point of the feasible region is optimal for the LP.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers I got it!